# How to structure Department-Employee data

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, data-structures, database-design

Currently I am trying to figure out the best way to design a suitable schema and structure for a Department document that would contain a list of employees and their positions, what I'm not sure about is how best to approach the structure of it would it be better to structure it with each department having an array of members that contain their position like:

## **Department**

- dept id.
- dept name
- dept division id
- ### Employees

  - id
  - name
  - department id
  - position

---

```
{
   departments : [
             { 
                id: 1,
                Name: xyz,
                divisionID: 123,
                employees: [ {  
                    memberName: abc,
                    position: Manager,
                    ...otherData
                },
                {  
                    memberName: abc,
                    position: Support,
                    ...otherData
                }
              ]
            }
       ]
    }
```

---

Or have it where the employee field would be a collection of positions with members in it like so:

- ## Department

  - ### Position

    - EmployeeData

---

```
members: [{ 
    Manager: [
        { id, name, etc...}
    ], 
    Support: [
        {id, name etc...}
    ],
}]
```

This is mainly to figure out which way to structure this relationship to more efficiently render the data on the client via ReactJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make separate collection for employees and put the its `_id` in `departments` `employees` array... So that it would be easy to make queries like populate and lookup when you would like get it

**departments collections**

```
{
   departments : [
             { 
                id: 1,
                Name: xyz,
                divisionID: 123,
                employees: [
                  ObjectId("1"),
                  ObjectId("2")
                ]
             }
         ]
     }
```

**employees collections**

```
{
       empoyees: [{ _id: ObjectId("1"), _id: ObjectId("2") }]
}
```

Comment: Would I also need to store a reference to the department _id in the employees collection?

Comment: It's up to you...  Because now lookup query does not required reference

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is best to keep each employee as a separate entity.

This way if you need to add/remove an employee (which will be more often then adding/removing departments) you will require fewer steps.

Comment: So would it be better then to store each employee as an individual and reduce the it into the position-employee structure for easier handling of the data when rendering it?